# Why do my mobile devices lose internet access but stay connected to wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

I have a number of mobile devices including iPhones, an iPad, and Kindle Fires. All of them can connect to my wifi network fine, and get Internet connectivity. After being idle for a variable amount of time (sometimes very short e.g. less than a minute) they lose Internet connectivity. When this happens, they maintain the wifi connection itself.

This problem does not happen on my laptops which include multiple Mac laptops and one Windows laptop.

I've tried a number of different things to resolve including upgrading OS versions and tweaking wifi router settings e.g. IP assignment TTL, signal type (B/G/N) and security mode, but no dice.

Any ideas why this happens and what I can do to fix it?

UPDATE: My AppleTV was also connected to the same wifi network, yet my iPhones couldn't see it to do AirPlay. Once I rebooted my router AirPlay was available again. AppleTV doesn't require a live Internet connection to do AirPlay, just requires a local wifi network. Because of this, I suspect the wifi router is dropping the network connectivity to the devices, or vice versa. It's not conclusive, but this seems to rule out the AT&T modem or router (which my wifi router connects to) being the problem.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is the access point itself.  Because I have all 3 of those devices and I personally don't have a problem.  Make sure each device is being given a different intranet ip address otherwise that might explain your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Each device does have a unique IP. I have also swapped out the wifi router to test the bad hardware theory, but the problem remains. Trying to think of a way the AT&T router (that my wifi router connects to) may be killing those connections somehow.

Comment: Well, Ramhound you have it. I purchased a 3rd device and it seems to be working quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramhound was correct. Even though I had tried two different wireless routers, the problem was fixed with trying a third wifi router. Considering my laptops didn't have connectivity problems it seems there was something deeper happening here, but there is very limited data to determine what. Considering the new router is working well I'm closing this one out.